# jquery select selector by name not returning selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHPNx/) and its working well. Also, it was working proper on my system until I'd uploaded it to server. The actual problem I'm getting is, wherever I'd used `$('select[name=propType]').val()` it always returning `Residential`.
I specially need that value `on line 76 of javascript in fiddle`.

Why it is not returning the exact `propType` selected value on my `localhost`? I'd used proper IDs wherever expected.
Any reason of such behavior?

**UPDATE**
The same code as of `fiddle` is not working on my site.

`line 75 in fiddle-javascript`
`$('select[name=propType]').val()` always returning `Residential`. Why?

Comment: You'll have to show us the page on your server otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @Itay: http://prithviassociates.org/html/post_requriment.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why `$('select[name=propType]').val()` not properly working well with me.
I'd changed those selectors with *id* as `$('#propType').val()` and `$(this).val()` applicable where needed.

Comment: Is that the solution for your problem?

Comment: I'd solved this problem in this way. But why it was not working in that way as I'd written in `fiddle`

Comment: This lines appears on `$("#propType").change` event. Why aren't you using `$(this).val()` instead of `$('select[name=propType]').val()`?

Comment: yeah.. I'd changed that line to `$(this).val()` but the actual problem was on `line 76 of javascript` in `fiddle`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#property').change(function ()
```

Please bind using

```
  $("body").delegate("#property", "change", function() {
   // your functionality come here
    });
```

Comment: what is the advantage of delegating change event?

Comment: There is not any advantage. But it will bind the event on element of the ajax response. If you want to know more about that please visit http://justprogrammer.com/2013/06/25/jquery-basic-concepts/